# How do I manually resize a PVC backed by IBM Cloud File / Block Storage?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

Let's say I'm hosting my pod that uses my pvc. My pvc only provisioned 10 Gi of storage, so my pod eventually crashes because it runs out of disk space. At this point, how do I add more space?

Preferably without losing data.

I am aware of `allowVolumeExpansion` https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims, but I don't think my cloud provider's storage classes `ibm.io/ibmc-file`, `ibm.io/ibmc-block`, and `vpc.block.csi.ibm.io` supports this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible on `ibm.io/ibmc-block`

Here is the documentation for [Storing data on classic IBM Cloud Block Storage](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-block_storage).

In section [Deciding on the block storage configuration](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-block_storage#block_predefined_storageclass) we can find:

> ### Important:
>
> Make sure to choose your storage configuration carefully to have enough capacity to store your data. After you provision a specific type of storage by using a storage class, you cannot change the size, type, IOPS, or retention policy for the storage device. If you need more storage or storage with a different configuration, you must create a new storage instance and copy the data from the old storage instance to your new one.

However this seems to be possible for `ibm.io/ibmc-file`, which is mentioned [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-file_storage#file_predefined_storageclass):

> ### Important:
>
> After you provision a specific type of storage by using a storage class, you cannot change the type, or retention policy for the storage device. However, you can change the size and the IOPS if you want to increase your storage capacity and performance. To change the type and retention policy for your storage, you must create a new storage instance and copy the data from the old storage instance to your new one.

This is described [Changing the size and IOPS of your existing storage device](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-file_storage#file_change_storage_configuration)

Comment: Thanks! https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-kube_concepts#update_storageclass Turns out you can for Classic Block Storage `ibmc-block` but not VPC Block Storage. Can you point me in the direction of how to "copy the data from the old storage instance to your new one"? I am using VPC Block Storage, so I can't resize...

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `.resources.requests.storage` field with the expected storage space.

To update you can run:

```sh
$ kubectl edit pvc <pvc_name>
```

You can verify this by running:

```sh
$ kubectl get pvc <pvc_name> -o yaml
```

This should do the work for you.

Reference: [Resizing Persistent Volumes using Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes)

Comment: This is only possible if the underlying StorageClass supports the operation, which at least some of the IBM classes the question is asking about do not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this confusion. You can change the size and IOPS of your block storage as well. See link here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-block_storage#block_change_storage_configuration

We will update the note.